# Mysql process takes 500 mb of primary memory

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, memory, mysql

I have a MBA 2013, and its not more than few days that I installed MySQL. I have not created any database in mysql yet, but still it takes a lot of memory on RAM. I have configured it to start automatically on boot up. So i would be glad if anyone can help me out with understanding why is that MySQL takes so much of memory and what is the solution to tune it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get exact memory allocation of any process with a quick command:

```
sudo sysdiagnose PID
```

(Where PID is the process ID of the mysql binary or the name of the mysql process you want to inspect deeply). There is a manual page and you will want to start with vmmap.txt and all memory files. I'm not certain that 500 mb of allocation is a problem or even of concern without understanding the options you have configured for the database and what the rest of your workload is.